# MVC Razor character issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I add the @ symbol to a razor view without it trying to rendor it?
The reason I ask is that in my footer I have some latest tweets and it shows the twitter username in the format **@username** but MVC is trying to parse it as code and throws a compilation error because **@username** does not exist in the current context (obviously).

Any help would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape it with an extra @.
Example:

```
@@TwiterName
```

Another solution is to use the following tags: `<text></text>`

Answer (score 2):

Try using this @@, voila the trick.

Answer (score 2):

you may use `<text>@name</text>` or @@ will work.

Answer (score 1):

Just like how the `\\` works which displays as `\` when printed on a console, use `@@` and then concat characters if that's what you need to display a single `@`